# ¿Cómo acceder a un objeto teniendo su dirección de memoria?

Tags: python, manejo-de-memoria

estoy intentando implementar una clase que funcione como los diccionarios, una tablas hash.

Pretendo que tenga una tabla (matriz unidimensional de numpy), y que cada casilla de la tabla, contenga la dirección de memoria a una lista, para que en caso de colisiones, esta agregue el nuevo elemento en la lista.

Tengo de momento lo siguiente

```
Class Hash():
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 10
        self.table = np.zeros((self.size), dtype=int)
        a = []
        for i in range(self.size):
            self.table[i] = id(a.copy())
```

Puedo cambiar o agregar hex() para tener la dirección de memoria en hexadecimal, pero luego no se qué hacer.

Cómo puedo después agregar algún elemento a la lista que está en la dirección de memoria de table[0] por ejemplo?

Comment: Y por qué guardas la dirección de memoria y no una lista en sí?. Además sabes que siempre guardas la misma dirección de memoria?

Comment: El trabajo no es práctico. Quería replicar la estructura de datos tal como funciona en c, pero con python. Esto me sirvió para entender como funciona internamente python. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respondo solo por la curiosidad, ya que al estar buscando no he encontrado mucho al respecto, por ende hago esta respuesta para que quede plasmado aquí.

Recordemos que la dirección de memoria es algo que cambia constantemente, por lo tanto no es recomendable manipularla. En tu caso no hay problema ya que solo accedemos a ella para modificar un objeto, el cual recibe su dirección de memoria de a cuerdo a lo que python y tu S.O. decidan.

Para poder hacer lo que pides necesitaremos del módulo `ctypes` que sirve para muchas cosas que requieran ser tratadas a más bajo nivel.

Pero antes de ir al código haré unas pequeñas correcciones en tu código. La primera es que no veo mucha lógica en definir ya un tamaño la tabla, es mejor si se le pasa el tamaño en el constructor. En segundo lugar tenemos la forma en que obtienes los id de las listas, lo cual es completamente erróneo.

Para obtener un `id` distinto cada vez que se ejecuta el código del `for` se debe crear un objeto nuevo y eso se logra haciendo `list()` que devuelve un nuevo objeto que sería una lista. Ya luego obtenemos su id con `id(list())`.

Tu código quedaría así:

```py
class Hash():
    def __init__(self, size=10):
        self.size = size
        self.table = np.zeros((self.size), dtype=int)
        for i in range(self.size):
            self.table[i] = id(list())
```

### Obteniendo objeto según su dirección de memoria

Como dije en un principio, usaremos el módulo `ctypes` del cual usaremos la función cast, lo que nos permite obtener un objeto en base a su dirección de memoria, esto en palabras simples.

Aquí el código:

```py
import numpy as np
import ctypes

#... codigo de clase Hash

mi_hash = Hash() #creamos una instancia de Hash
mi_id = mi_hash.table[0] #obtenemos una dirección de memoria de la tabla
print(mi_id) #imprimimos para ver

#obtenemos el valor del objeto
val_mi_id = ctypes.cast(mi_id, ctypes.py_object).value
#luego ya podemos hacer lo que queramos con el objeto
print(val_mi_id)
```

La función `cast` nos retorna un objeto de tipo `ctypes.py_object` y debemos obtener su valor, por ello accedemos a su atributo `value` al final, lo cual ya nos regresará el objeto python.

---

**Sugerencias**
Como te dije en mi comentario, no entiendo porqué guardar el id de una lista, es mejor que guardes una lista en si ya que esto te facilita las cosas. Por otra parte es no crear una tabla con 10 listas, mejor ve agregando las listas con forme vayas agregando elementos a tu clase `Hash`.

**Nota:** esto no lo pruebes en Google Colab >_<.

Si tienes alguna pregunta o duda puedes hacérmela saber en los comentarios :D.

Comment: gracias! Esto solucionó mi problema :D